# Symfony 2.1 Extending Core Classes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am trying to override the core Symfony components with my own. The method I am using is:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { 
                "": "src/",
                "Symfony": "src/vendor/symfony/src/"
             }
}
```

However when I run composer update and install it never seems to take this into account. Is this not the correct method to force the autoloader to look into another directory first before the Symfony core?

Any pointers appreciated!

EDIT: Paths to files

src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/TranslationExtension.php

src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php
src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Twig_Extensions_' => $vendorDir . '/twig/extensions/lib/',
    'Twig_' => $vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib/',
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\SwiftmailerBundle' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/',
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/monolog-bundle/',
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/assetic-bundle/',
    'Symfony' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src/', '/src/vendor/symfony/src/'),
    'SessionHandlerInterface' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs',
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\GeneratorBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sensio/generator-bundle/',
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/',
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sensio/distribution-bundle/',
    'Monolog' => $vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/',
    'Metadata\\' => $vendorDir . '/jms/metadata/src/',
    'JMS\\SecurityExtraBundle' => $vendorDir . '/jms/security-extra-bundle/',
    'JMS\\DiExtraBundle' => $vendorDir . '/jms/di-extra-bundle/',
    'JMS\\AopBundle' => $vendorDir . '/jms/aop-bundle/',
    'Doctrine\\ORM' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib/',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib/',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib/',
    'Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/',
    'CG\\' => $vendorDir . '/jms/cg/src/',
    'Assetic' => $vendorDir . '/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/',
    '' => $baseDir . '/src/',
);
```

If I manually edit the autoload line to:

```
'Symfony' => array('/Users/macbook/Sites/Opia/Gaia/src/vendor/symfony/src/', $vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src/'),
```

Everything works as it is meant to. So now it is basically finding the solution to why composer does not compose properly.

EDIT 2:

Doing some more searching it appears the above method is not a good implementation:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/composer-dev/HprRV_wJZg4/M_zQ8O7lB6IJ

Instead I need to extend the given classes and tell Symfony to use those classes instead which should be possible through the parameters:

```
parameters: 
security.authentication.listener.anonymous.class: Acme\DemoBundle 
\Security\Http\Firewall\AcmeAnonymousAuthenticationListener
```

However I am not sure what parameters I need to set to load the extended classes in place of the core.

Comment: What is the path of your file inside `src/vendor/symfony/src/` ?

Comment: Edited my original posts with path(s). I think that is what you meant, if not let know.

Comment: Can you also include `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` ?

Comment: Added, it appears the path is there, is it supposed to be before the other?

Comment: Yep, it should be before the main one. Is your composer.phar up to date ? You can update it by running `composer self-update`

Comment: I ran self-update and got: Updating to version 62bb5b3. Then did and update an install and still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this.

Firstly if you need to find out which classes to override go to:

```
symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/%Your file to override%.xml
```

There you will find a list of possible Symfony classes that can be extended/overridden.

Then in your config.yml add (I chose to put mine in an extend namespace):

```
parameters:
  twig.extension.trans.class: Extend\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension
  translation.loader.yml.class: Extend\Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader
  translator.class: Extend\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator
```

Finally in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { 
                "": "src/",
                "Extend\\Symfony": "/path/to/your/symfony/classes"
             }
},
```

Comment: This is indeed a better way, relying on name-clashes for overriding classes means that you can not extend the original class but will have to copy-paste the whole code, which is hardly the most maintainable solution.

Comment: You should still be able to extend the class by simply referring to the base class as something different so: use Symfony/path/to/Translator as SymphonyTranslator. Then Translator extends SymfonyTranslator (I have not tested this but seems like it would work fine)