# How to set default route parameter from session?

Tags: symfony, routes

If I have a batch of routes looking like this:

```
/{location}/catalog
/{location}/search
```

etc.

Session always has "location" attribute (alias to auto-recognized user location, e.g. city). So, to generate each route with {location} parameter, i need to do

```
{ location: session.get('location') }
```

Is there are any way to do this automatically? Can I override default UrlGenerator and inject @session into it?

Comment: i have solution to use with twig. I define a twig extension with injected "session" and "router" and create custom "location_path" function with merged params. But i have to replace path() in all templates and its not the best solution i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try override RoutingExtension class /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/CodeExtension.php
[Symfony 2.1 Extending Core Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749524/symfony-2-1-extending-core-classes)

Also you could fork https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge and use it with composer http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Comment: Thanks! To sad, but seems the only way is fork TwigBridge (it is impossible to inject additional services into RoutingExtension, i can only specify a class). So i prefer to replace all path functions instead. It will be easier to support.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new EventSubscriber like this..
This documentation is similar https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html

```
// src/EventSubscriber/LocationSubscriber.php
class LocationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{
    private $router;
    private $defaultLocation;

    public function __construct(string $defaultLocation = "Vigo", RequestContextAwareInterface $router = null)
    {
        $this->router          = $router;
        $this->defaultLocation = $defaultLocation;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the location has been set as a _location routing parameter
        if ($location = $request->attributes->get('_location')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_location', $location);
        } else {
            // if no explicit location has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $location = $request->getSession()->get('_location', $defaultLocation);
        }

        // set Router Context from session
        if (null !== $this->router) {
            $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_location', $location);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```